# Deleting file in subdirectory using find and confirmation

Tags: unix, find, delete-file

I am trying to delete a specific file (an executable installed by several people and located inside their home directory) using the find command. The folder structure is as following

```
    /home/usr1/folder/l32/fileToDelete
    /home/usr1/folder/l32/dontDelete
    /home/usr2/folderABC/l32/fileToDelete
    /home/usr2/folderABC/l32/dontDelete
    /home/usr3/folder/l32/fileToDelete
    /home/usr3/folder/l32/dontDelete
    /home/usr10/folderXYZ/whatever/l32/fileToDelete
    /home/usr10/folderXYZ/whatever/l32/dontDelete
```

ultimately the executable file will always be inside the l32 folder.
I use the following command to locate all the files and this works

```
find -type d -name "l32" -exec find {} -depth -type f -name fileToDelete-executable \;
```

However, if I try to use rm -i {} as below, I get a "rm:cannot remove `./home/usr1/folder/l32': Is a directory error

```
find -type d -name "l32*" -exec find {} -depth -type f -name fileToDelete -executable \; -exec rm -i {} \;
```

if I use rm -rfi {} then it works but it asks me if I want to descend into each subdirectory and also if I want to delete the files I actually don't want to delete.

```
find -type d -name "l32*" -exec find {} -depth -type f -name fileToDelete -executable \; -exec rm -rfi {} \;
```

Ultimately, I just want to delete that specific executable file that is located in a specific subdirectory. I also tried xargs but that didn't work wither

```
find -type d -name "l32*" -exec find {} -depth -type f -name fileToDelete -executable \; | xargs rm -i --
```

Does anyone know why this is not working.
Note: Yes I could use the -delete option but I would like to be asked for confirmation for each file

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this:

```
find . -type f -name "fileToDelete" -path "*/l32/*" -exec rm -i {} \;
```

- option `-path` allows you to specify a path you want to filter on.
- it is often used with option `-not` to filter out a path where you would NOT want to delete a file that matches the `-name` option.